# Create a dynamic horizontal repeating table in Infopath 2013 based on a previously given number?

Tags: c#, ms-office, infopath

Problem:
You have a regular repeating table when it comes to the rows but need the columns to repeat as well based on the difference between two fields.

Ex. The difference field has the value 4 so the table needs to have 4 columns (The number of rows is already variable because of the repeating table control).

The problem also lies in the fact that there is no maximum difference, it can be any value, so creating all the columns and adding formatting rules to hide them isn't a feasible solution.

Is there any way that using C# we can create a new field or table, or access a previously created table in the Infopath form?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nj5xOuveD-CHTSJkgJOm_qnxKf5KTBr4OTdSJMMUKKw/edit?usp=sharing

The link above is an excel sheet with a small demonstration of the expected output.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you possibly create an excel document or something else visibly displaying what you mean?

Comment: @cdomination An excel sheet demonstrating the data is attached to the originial post, Thank you.